# we opened ports 1433 and 1434 from datavault server, app server to database server

Tags: sql-server-2019

we opened ports 1433 and 1434 from datavault server, app server to database server. ports are opened but we are unable to work on port 1434

Port 1434: When we tested this port, it was opened and was listening on the database server, but for some reason it had been giving us a warning saying that “portqry.exe -n ip.xxx.xx.xx -e 1434 -p UDP exits with return code 0x00000002”.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? For example, are you having trouble connecting to a named instance? (UDP 1434 is typically used to resolve named instances.)

Comment: we want to connect port 1433 and 1434 both ports to default instance?does both ports work on default instance from application server and data vault server?

Comment: An instance is bound to a single port. (Well, for all practical purposes. There are edge case for the Dedicated Admin Connection and for named instances.) What problem are you trying to solve? _Why_ do you want to use 1434? And/or, what is it that you are trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: we have application server and datavault server .... client wants application server to use 1434 and datavault server 1433..... 1433 is working to destination db server..... 1434 is not working ...how to allow traffic to 1434 udp from database server?

Comment: Is there any command to test 1434 UDP from source server to destination server?

Comment: I'm not sure why the client would want SQL to listen on two different ports. It can be done, but it is very unusual. You would have to do that in the SQL Server Configuration Manager utility. List both ports, separated by commas, in the TCP Port field. (See https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/07/24/sql-server-how-to-listen-on-multiple-tcp-ports-in-sql-server/) If I'm understanding you correctly, UDP becomes irrelevant.

Comment: I will try that and see.. Thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

That return code is not a warning. Portqry returns this code because UDP does not send ACK responses.

IF portqry reports that it is "listening" on 1434 UDP, then there is no issue with sending UDP traffic to the tested destination.